# Get the texts from div with same class and display them on another div

Tags: html, jquery

What I want to achieve is if this `<div class="btn"><span class="evening">Display Code</span></div>` is clicked, I want to get the texts inside from each div with class 'codes' if `.bet` class has `.open` class and display them on `<div id="display-results"></div>`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').each(function() {

    $(this).on('click', function() {

      var theClass = $('span', this).attr('class');

      $('.bet-' + theClass).each(function() {

        if ($('.bet-' + theClass + ' .bet').hasClass('open')) {

          // GET the text inside code and display them on #display-results
          // Results example = <div id="display-results">C, D</div>r
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bet-morning">
  <div class="morning">
    <div class="code">A</div>
    <div class="bet open">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-morning">
  <div class="morning">
    <div class="code">B</div>
    <div class="bet close">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-evening">
  <div class="evening">
    <div class="code">C</div>
    <div class="bet open">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-evening">
  <div class="evening">
    <div class="code">D</div>
    <div class="bet open">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-evening">
  <div class="evening">
    <div class="code">E</div>
    <div class="bet close">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="btn"><span class="morning">Display Code</span></div>
<div class="btn"><span class="evening">Display Code</span></div>


<div id="display-results"></div>
```

Comment: There's no element with a `codes` class

Comment: `$("." + theClass + " .bet.open").each(...)`

Comment: Yes sorry, class 'code' not 'codes'. I want to get the letters inside the class 'code'

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues

1. Far too convoluted access to the elements. Rarely use for .each in jQuery
2. You seem to want the sibling-div's letter of the open element

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var theClass = '.bet-'+$('span', this).attr('class');
    $('#display-results').text(
      $('.bet.open',theClass) 
        .map(function() { 
          return $(this).prev(".code").text() // grab the letter from the sibling - ".code" is optional
        }).get().join(', ') // return an array and join it
    )
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bet-morning">
  <div class="morning">
    <div class="code">A</div>
    <div class="bet open">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-morning">
  <div class="morning">
    <div class="code">B</div>
    <div class="bet close">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-evening">
  <div class="evening">
    <div class="code">C</div>
    <div class="bet open">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-evening">
  <div class="evening">
    <div class="code">D</div>
    <div class="bet open">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bet-evening">
  <div class="evening">
    <div class="code">E</div>
    <div class="bet close">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="btn"><span class="morning">Display Code</span></div>
<div class="btn"><span class="evening">Display Code</span></div>


<div id="display-results"></div>
```